# External JPanel not displayed into JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have a `JFrame` and a `JPanel`, and I desire that the `JPanel` is shown in the `JFrame`.

I have written the following code:

```
public MainScreen() {
    initComponents();        
    setVisible(false);
    setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    PnlButons pnlButons = new PnlButons();
    pnlButons.setSize(pnlButons.getHeight(),JFrame.MAXIMIZED_VERT);

    add(pnlButons,BorderLayout.WEST);
    setVisible(true);
    pack();
}
```

I tried many tutorials, but none of them helped and the `JPanel` isn't displayed.

Comment: BorderLayout works with `prefferedSize`, so set prefSize or override getPrefSize() method

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Yep.. works just fine here in my SSCCE based on that code.

Comment: Sorry for not to post an SSCCE code. I'm using netbeans for programing.

Comment: *"Sorry for not to post an SSCCE code. I'm using netbeans for programing."*   Netbeans can create SSCCEs, even using the GUI designer.  BTW - That reads here like you are your IDEs bitch - it ***owns you***.  I suggest you change that as the first priority.

Comment: `pack()` _then_ `setVisible()`; see also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Swing extends JFrame{

    Swing() {
    //    initComponents();        
        setVisible(false);
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        JButton pnlButons = new JButton();
        pnlButons.setSize(pnlButons.getHeight(),JFrame.MAXIMIZED_VERT);

        add(pnlButons,BorderLayout.WEST);
        setVisible(true);
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Swing();
    }
}
```

and Here is the link to for your screen.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/wncelkzj9rwxlwj/SOVImage.png

Comment: I just copied an pasted your code to see how it is behaving and I changed pnlButtons to JButton because I am not aware with pnlButtons.Its working,I was able to see a button on left

Comment: I need to display a JPanel, that will contain buttons. I build the JPanel in grafical mode, but now I need that it will be displayed into the jframe parent.

Comment: My appology I did'nt understand your graphical mode.But as far as I am getting,you want to show buttons which is attached to JPanel and this panel in turn is attached to JFRAME.If it is the case then we need to create number of JButton objects and add it on the JPanel by selecting desired Layout.

Answer (score 0):

set the size of your JPanel by `setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height)`

Comment: See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)